# Pydantic validate_arguments on a dataclass

Tags: python, pydantic, python-dataclasses

I have a problem with python 3.11, dataclasses and (ancient) pydantic (due to one lib's dependencies, pydantic==1.10)

I have a base class, let's call it `A`
and then a few subclasses, like `B`.

Then in one of the functions, I pass in an instance of `B`, and verify

```
if isinstance(b, B):
```

which it fails.

```
from dataclasses import dataclass
from pydantic import validate_arguments


@dataclass
class A:
    foo: int = 1


@validate_arguments
@dataclasss(kw_only=True)
class B(A):
    foo: int = 2


type(B)
isinstance(B(), B)

>>> type(B)
<class 'cython_function_or_method'>

>>> isinstance(B(), B)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: isinstance() arg 2 must be a type, a tuple of types, or a union

>>> isinstance(B(), type(B))
False
```

But it works without the `validate_arguments` decorator

```
@dataclass
class B(A):
    foo: int = 2

type(B)
isinstance(B(), B)

>>> isinstance(B(), B)
True
```

Is this a problem with this ancient pydantic or am I just things wrong?
I am stuck with pydantic==1.0 until that lib upgrades dependencies which may or may not be quick.

Answer (score 0):

Its because isinstance second argument is expected to be classes/list of classes not function
`isinstance(object, classinfo)`
in your example B is not a type of class but type(B) is class type.

```
>>> B
<cyfunction B at 0x7fbce1098a00>
>>> type(B)
<class 'cython_function_or_method'>
```

same check fails with below example

```
>>> def a():
...     return 'A'
... 
>>> isinstance(a(), a)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: isinstance() arg 2 must be a type, a tuple of types, or a union
>>> a
<function a at 0x7fbce1288670>
>>> type(a)
<class 'function'>

>>> isinstance(a, type(a))
True
>>>
```